# IonicV4 Menu Component inside Split Pane not showing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to build an app with Ionic V4. I'm following Ionic Docs but It's a headache even for simplest things.

I want to show a split pane with a side menu. The side menu is a component with this html:

**menu.component.html**

```
<ion-menu contentId="content1">
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menú</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

In the other side

**app.component.html**

```
<ion-app>
<ion-split-pane>
    <app-menu></app-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="content1" main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-split-pane>
```

And I get a blank side menu like this

[image]

But, if I paste the menu.component's HTML instance of  I see everything fine

[image]

**EDIT**: I've forget to mention that I use Ionic 4 beta 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for some reason the `<ion-menu>` must be direct child of `<ion-split-pane>`. You can still however create a separate menu component using angular routing like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MenuPage,
    children: [
      { path: 'tab1', loadChildren: './tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule' },
      { path: 'tab2', loadChildren: './tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule' },
      { path: 'tab3', loadChildren: './tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule' },
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/tab1', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ],
  },
```

The MenuPage template contains ion-split-pane with menu and ion-router-outlet to render the actual content into :

```
<ion-split-pane>
  <ion-menu>
  // ...
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet id="content" main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-split-pane>
```

Here's full working sample: https://github.com/MattiLehtinen/ionic4-split-pane-menu-sample